# Why is the past-perfect used in this?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

> Remember the chocolate and the scarf you gave me? I hadn't returned the favor for that until now.

Why is the past-perfect (I hadn't returned) used in this, instead of the present-perfect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of past perfect suggests that the speaker has just then (prior to making the statement) returned the favor. In other words, previously the favor had not been returned, but now it has.

> - Here, I got you a new wallet. I hope you like it!
> - Thank you! But why?
> - Remember the chocolate and the scarf you gave me? I hadn't returned the favor for that until now.
> - Thank you!

Of course, you did not cite the source or give any context,  so it could be that the past perfect is being used in a different (and possibly incorrect) way.